# Singular or plural "possession/s" in Hebrews 10:34?

Tags: hebrews, linguistics

Hebrews 10:34
New International Version

> You suffered along with those in prison and joyfully accepted the confiscation of your property, because you knew that you yourselves had better and lasting **possessions**.

English Standard Version

> For you had compassion on those in prison, and you joyfully accepted the plundering of your property, since you knew that you yourselves had a better **possession** and an abiding one.

possession.
ὕπαρξιν (hyparxin)
Noun - Accusative Feminine **Singular**
Strong's 5223: Goods, substance, property, possessions. From huparcho; existency or proprietorship, i.e. property, wealth.

At https://biblehub.com/hebrews/10-34.htm, 11 versions use the plural form and 11 versions use singular. Why is there this difference?
Is this perhaps an English language issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in Heb 10:34 is not just with the last word in the verse but also with one of the other central words.  Here is the version from BLB -

> For both you sympathized with the prisoners and you accepted the
> plundering of your **possessions** with joy, knowing yourselves to
> have a better and abiding **possession**.

- The first highlighted word, ὑπαρχόντων, is plural (from ὑπάρχω), which many versions translate in the singular
- The second highlighted word, ὕπαρξιν, is singular (from ὕπαρξις), which many translate in the plural

Perversely, some reverse both and some make both plural and some make both singular.  I can justify none of this - I prefer the literal version above in this case.

The first highlighted word above appears to be referring to many household items (hence the plural) as "possessions"; the second highlighted word appears to be referring to a property or estate - the totality of one's home - a reference to the heavenly home provided by God, although it may also refer to the possession of the truth of the Gospel in Jesus which cannot be confiscated.  [The "in heaven" of the KJV, TR, Majority and Byzantine texts is questionable.]

The Cambridge Bible commentary has this:

> **knowing in yourselves that ye have in heaven** The “in heaven” is almost certainly a spurious gloss, and the “in” before “yourselves”
> should be unquestionably omitted. If the true reading be ἐαυτοῖς, the
> meaning is “recognising that ye have for yourselves,” but if we may
> accept ἑαυτούς, the reading of א, we have the very beautiful and
> striking thought, “recognising that ye have yourselves as a better
> possession and an abiding.” He points them to the tranquil
> self-possession of a holy heart (Luke 9:25; Luke 21:19), the
> acquisition of our own souls, as a sufficient present consolation for
> the loss of earthly goods (Hebrews 11:26), independently of the
> illimitable future hope (Matthew 6:20; Romans 8:18; 1 Peter 1:4-8).

Ellicott appears to agree -

> **for a better possession and one that abideth** They had been taught the meaning of the words spoken by Jesus of the man who gains the
> world and loses himself (Luke 9:25), and of those who win their souls
> by their endurance (Luke 21:19); so in Hebrews 10:39 the writer speaks
> of “the gaining of the soul.” Thus trained, they could accept with joy
> the loss of possessions for the sake of Christ, perceiving that in Him
> they had received themselves as a possession, a better and a lasting
> possession. (It would be possible to render the clause, “knowing that
> ye yourselves have a better possession,” &c.; but the parallelism of
> Hebrews 10:39 renders it almost certain that the former view of the
> words is correct.)